# How to create a educational video by only using your voice and some photos

Tags: video-quality, video-recording, mac

I would like to create some educational videos in which I will use only my voice and some photos/text headlines, notes etc. on my Mac computer. I am aiming at creating videos that are as much as possible in better definition while as much as possible smaller size in order to make them upload easily. All I think is two options.

First one is I can create a video using slides and then record my voice over it by using a video editing program.
Secondly, I can create a slide and record a voice over it while screen recording.

Second one sounds easier for me because I can be more flexible on timing and duration.

I can use Quicktime for screen recording. Do you think it is a good idea for a video? Its recordings can be very large size. I do not think I need super-quality definition on my videos. 480p is good enough for me.

What are your suggestions in terms of video recording techniques and applications/programs for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerPoint.

The truth is that the latest version of it can do nice transitions so the presentation is not dull at all.

At the end, you can export as a video to Mp4. If used properly you do not need video edition at all.

Do not use less than HD for your videos. The resolution may not be important to you, but the viewers are used to Full HD.

Comment: Thank you buddy

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, Keynote is free, and works well. You could prepare your slides, then open Quicktime Player to do a screen record whilst you record your audio and run your slides.

It's a good idea to have lots of hard drive space when working on a video - the files can be large, but then you can make a smaller compressed version for sharing afterwards.

If the file size is large at the end, you can choose how you save it afterwards in Quicktime using the "Export As" option in the File Menu. 4K will result in large files and high resolution. 480p will give smaller files but a lot lower resolution.

If you want more precision, and the ability to go back and fix mistakes etc, you may need to use a video editing package such as iMovie (free and inlcuded with MacOS), or Premiere (paid).  [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) (paid) is also excellent and designed for recording and editing screen recordings.

Comment: Thank you for  concise answer. I made a video using Keynote and Quicktime yesterday. The video 45 minutes long, in 720p  and its size is around 1 GB! It took 30 minutes to upload it but when I  tried to export to it as 480p, it lasted around 2 hours! Why does it take so long? It is a pity that Quicktime does not allow us to choose the definition of the video before recording. It could be problem when the internet connection has slow for large videos. So I try to find out the ways of decreasing the size of videos I make.

Comment: Hi. Videos are big files. There are a lot of pixels in a 720p video, and they can all change at any time! A 45 min video at around 1GB sounds about right to me.  You could compress the file to make it smaller, but the quality will get worse. Video compression is a trade-off between file size and quality. You could try an app like Handbrake (free) to recompress your video and see whether the quality is still acceptable. https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php